# Как можно проанализировать качество Java проекта?

Tags: java

Один мой коллега обратился ко мне с просьбой проанализировать написанный его группой программистов проект. Проект писался в течении 4-х лет группой из 10 программистов, с использованием технологии Spring. Можете ли вы поделиться некоторыми идеями, какие инструменты, методы и классификаторы вы используете для анализа качества написания проектов написанных на Java.

Comment: У нас в проекте использовался http://www.sonarsource.com/ для таких целей. А вообще можно наверное использовать любую тулзу из: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Качество написания проекта", на мой взгляд, складывается из двух вещей:

1. Низкоуровневой: непосредственно качество кода. Для такой проверки используйте статический анализатор кода, он найдет потенциально проблемные места (логические ошибки в условиях, опасные паттерны и т.д.). Существуют как отдельные тулы, так и встроенные в IDE (например, в IntelliJ Idea).
2. Высокоуровневой: качество проектирование, адекватность архитектуры решения. Такое оценивается только анализом требований и готового решения, и требует немалого опыта. Но позволяет ответить на разные вопросы, например: Не загнется ли проект через полгода от незначительных изменений в требованиях? Сложно ли вносить изменения в существующий код? В какой-то степени это даже более важное качество, чем качество кода, поскольку исправлять ошибки этого уровня очень сложно и дорого.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь статическим анализатором. Ссылку на их список вам дали в комментарии.
Так же стоит провести профилирование и нагрузочное тестирование (на wiki так же есть списки инструментов).

Answer (score 0):

[PMD](https://pmd.github.io/)  стандард, в целом, для этих целей со всеми плюшками и в Eclipse и для Jenkins.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?